# Can I study French at France without visa (Schengen rule) or need a student visa?

Tags: visa, france, student-visa, language-course

I'm considering learning French at France, and as a Japanese citizen I can stay for up to 90 days at the Schengen area without any visa.

Now, in order to obtain the student visa, I must go back to Japan (where I don't live in), do lots of paperworks and interview at the French embassy at Tokyo, and also get charged with a steep application fee. So I rather want to make the study period less than 90 days and study there without getting visa.

But is this possible or do I have to obtain a student visa even though the duration is less than 90 days?

Comment: What is your country of residence?

Comment: @Traveller Mainland China

Comment: Schengen visa applications must normally be submitted in the applicant’s country of residence. Is there a reason why you believe you have to return to Japan to apply rather than apply in China? https://fr.tlscontact.com/cn/BJS/splash.php?l=en

Comment: @Traveller It is not the Schengen visa but the student visa for France, which is only applicable to France. I have read I must apply from my own country; at least the working holiday visa must be applied from my own country even if I live in other countries, which was written at the Embassy website (I saw it when I was considering it but eventually gave up due to the reason).

Comment: https://fr.tlscontact.com/cn/splash.php?l=fr also indicates application from country of residence.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan It is still not clear to me if the resident includes foreigners. But anyway, my question still stands since it requires the daunting paperwork and steep application fee, anyway.

Comment: @Blaszard According to  http://www.studying-in-france.org/visa-and-entry-requirements/ Japanese citizens do not need a visa to study for up to 90 days

Comment: Note that in the grand scheme of things, the fees are not particularly steep. It's only slightly more than the fees for a Schengen short-stay visa, less than half the fees of a comparable UK visa (if you apply from China).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need a student visa. The Schengen regulations cover all short-stays in France no matter their purpose. You don't need one in your case but there is even a box “study” on the standard [Schengen short-stay visa application form](https://www.diplomatie.gouv.fr/IMG/pdf/Formulaire_SCH_eng.pdf) and your visa-free stay would be governed by the same rules.

Should you need a French long-stay visa for another purpose, note that applying from your country of residence (as opposed to your country of origin) is [generally fine](https://www.demarches.interieur.gouv.fr/particuliers/visa-long-sejour-sejour-mois-an). Work-holiday visas are a very particular beast as they are rooted in bilateral agreements. There are also some special rules regarding student visas as many people have to apply online first.